# binding.node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: angular

I am getting error while installing node modules for my angular 6 project.

```
Binary has a problem: Error: \\?\C:\demo\WA3Projects\securedmessaginglastest\collection\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-67\binding.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\demo\WA3Projects\securedmessaginglastest\collection\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-67\binding.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at module.exports (C:\demo\WA3Projects\securedmessaginglastest\collection\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:19:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\demo\WA3Projects\securedmessaginglastest\collection\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
Building the binary locally
```

I tried to make work around by opening powershell script and keeps waiting and saying say Still waiting for installer log file...

```
npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
```